# custom static broadcastreceiver not working when app is removed from recent apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

when my app is removed from recent apps, my custom broadcastreceiver is not working, onreceive can't be excuted any more, but we know system broadcast can be received when app is removed from recent apps.is the phenomenon right? or is my custom broadcastreceiver not true? thanks for help.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="action_alarm_trigger_sync" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction(AlarmBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
serviceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
PendingIntent servicePendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
       AlarmBroadcastReceiver.SERVICE_ID, serviceIntent,
       PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  
am.setRepeating(
       AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
       cal.getTimeInMillis(),
       interval,
       servicePendingIntent
);
```

`BroadcastReceiver` code (pasted from a comment):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("AlarmManager","AlarmBroadcastReceiver start");
    try {
        FileUtils.writeFileSdcardFile("hhaa"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 


public static void writeFileSdcardFile(String write_str) throws IOException {
    File mFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/alram_record2.text");
    if(!mFile.exists()){
        mFile.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(mFile, true);
    byte [] bytes = write_str.getBytes();
    fout.write(bytes);
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: I encountered a similar error when I was debugging my app. Disconnect debugging and run the app from the home screen and try.

Comment: unfortunately,the result is the same.can you tell me the error you have encountered?

Comment: When I ran my code from android studio the receiver would work but if I force closed the app device recents the receiver would not get called. So what I did was run it from the home screen instead which worked for some reason.

Comment: what device are you testing on? Please post the code from your `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: nexus 6  android 5.1.1                                                                                          @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("AlarmManager","AlarmBroadcastReceiver start");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeFileSdcardFile("hhaa"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+"\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: You should remove the `<category>` from the `<intent-filter>` in your `<receiver>`. But I don't know why it isn't triggered when removed from recent apps. Add the code from `FileUtils.writeFileSdcardFile()` to your post please. Please don't put the code in a comment (it isn't readable). Just edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver" />
```

and:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.SERVICE_ID, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, servicePendingIntent);
```

Comment: when my app is running, broadcast can be received, so i don't think the problem is related to 'serviceIntent'